# Android MediaCodec java.nio.BufferOverflowException

Tags: java, android, h.264, encode, android-mediacodec

I want to encode a video from camera to H.264. To do this I'm using [this code](https://gist.github.com/wobbals/3990442) .

The problem is that I'm getting `java.nio.BufferOverflowException` in `offerEncoder` function at this line `inputBuffer.put(input);`.

I've discovered that the `input.length = 2332800` and `inputBuffer.limit()=520192`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Or another workaround to achieve encoding to H.264? I saw some posts about this issue, but those didn't helped me.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, your input data is 2.2 MB large, while the input buffers are only 508 KB large. Your example code shows setting up the encoder for 320x240 (where the input buffers would only be about 112 KB large), while your input data seems to be way too big for that. Conversely - what size are your input frames? Make sure this matches the parameters you're setting in the encoder.